# How to write formula with a special character I've never seen?

Tags: html, special-characters

I need to display the following formula in HTML (simplified example):

```
       ->     ->
d = || BA  ^  u  ||
```

Is there a special character/entity, that displays an arrow (like this one: →) directly above a character (like as you would write Ã or Â - just with an arrow instead of a tilde or circ).

I have never seen something like this. Can this be done with HTML?

Comment: I don't quite know the answer but here's a hint that might be useful: Zalgo text. l̶͓͌͗̿͌́̑ō̸̼͍̬͖̻̦̈́̔̒̓͠l̸̼̞̄̍̈́ You can generate that with sites like https://lingojam.com/ZalgoText and sometimes it happens that an arrow pointing to both sides is used as a garbage character. So that sorta exists in a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML Entities** help in incorporating special characters into our HTML documents. Please check the chart from here https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

If not found in the list: We can use our own CSS to do so:

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0 0.8rem;
}
.character {
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.chars {
  margin: 0 0.4rem;
}
```

```html
   <section class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- this is where the fun begins... -->

  <div class="chars">D</div>
  <div class="chars">=</div>
  <div class="chars">|&nbsp;|</div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="arrow">&rarr;</div>
    <div class="character">BA</div>
  </div>

  <div>^</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="arrow">&rarr;</div>
    <div class="character">u</div>
  </div>

  <div class="chars">|&nbsp;|</div>
</section>
```

Comment: if it's not in that list, it does not exist ?

Comment: I have found a way to do this. Let me update the answer :)

Comment: We can add some extra CSS to keep the arrow as close to the character as we want :) Does this help

Comment: @JonSnow Full Code provided for you :) Happy Coding. If this helps do kindly accept the answer by clicking on tick icon for others to benefit from. Thanks

Comment: I love both solutions here, but I feel that your css solution might be easier to implement at the end of the day (see my comment below the other solution). 
So yeah, super helpful! Thank you very much for your time and I'll mark your answer now as accepted

Comment: You are most welcome :) And Thanks for accepting my answer. It gives me such a great pleasure to be a part of coding world and help and support one another. Learn from one another :) Coding rocks

Answer (score 2):

You could try https://latex.codecogs.com/ for creating gifs "on-the-fly" for inclusion in any HTML (or markup):

```
d=\left \|{ \overrightarrow{BA} \wedge \overrightarrow{u} }\right \|
```

[image: d=\left\|{\overrightarrow{BA}\wedge\overrightarrow{u}}\right\|)]

You can basically do anything that you would with TeX or LaTeX ...

Comment: That looks super interesting!! Maybe that could really help.What have you entered to the form on that page to achieve THAT result?  I don't know what you mean with TeX or LaTeX, to be honest...

Comment: I seems to me that it might be too difficult for the colleagus to create the correct formulas :-/  An wedge is not correct, it should have been a circ at that position, which seems to not be available. Or have I just overseen ist?

Comment: :D - Well, yes, TeX and LaTeX certainly require some "getting used to"! But they are capable of creating some beautifully set equations ...